# iOS prevent scrolling with overlay

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I have a wordpress site with a basic homepage structure like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div id="scrolling-body">
            //lots of stuff here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
div.overlay {
    background:#000000;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 15s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    overflow-y:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}

div.overlay.active {
    z-index: 10000;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

And I toggle my `active` class with simple jQuery.

My issue is that when the overlay is `active`, I can still scroll `#scrolling-body` but only on iOS mobile devices. I prevent scrolling on other devices like this (`scroll` is calculated when `active` is toggled):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).scrollTop(scroll);
});
```

I have tried the touchstart solutions that are mentioned here on SO (cant find links now). They don't work. What else do I need to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I get how this could only be an issue on ios, buut... As far as a cross browser solution goes: You could add a new class that forces the site to collapse when  the overlay is active and remove the class when overlay is hidden. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fegp5msL/). This is a static example, but the idea is, when the class is later on removed, the site will get back to normal.

Comment: Since it was simple, as a proof of concept, [here's another example where clicking the overlay removes the overlay and the class.](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fegp5msL/1/)

Comment: There is an issue with your example that when you toggle that class, it scrolls the content back to the top. See your second example. I've updated it.

Comment: even that scrolls it up. With regards to remembering the position, i did that, but what iOS does is it scrolls and then when the scrolling is done, it just jumps to the old position.

Comment: Don't do the same mistake I did in the previous comment that I removed :) This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fegp5msL/5/ ( click to open overlay in about the middle of the page ) Just remember to get the scroll position before adding the class and set the scroll position after removing the class. **Lines:** 1, 6 and 21

Comment: @Joonas Thanks that just helped me out, I didn't think to hide the overflow on the HTML too.